# One-to-many relationship always changed into many-to-one by PowerBI

Tags: foreign-keys, relationship, data-visualization, powerbi

I have two tables from Azure SQL in PowerBI, using direct query:

- `EMP(empID PK)`
- `contactInfo(contactID PK, empID FK, contactDetail)`

which have an obvious one-to-many relationship from `EMP.empID` to `contactInfo.empID`. The foreign key constraint is successfully enforced.

However I can only create a many-to-one relationship (`contactInfo.empID` to `EMP.empID`) in PowerBI. If I ever try the opposite, PowerBI always automatically converts the relationship to many-to-one (by swapping the from and to column), which prevents me from creating visuals. Does PowerBI think the two are equivalent?

**Update:**

What I'm doing is to just create a table in PowerBI showing the join results of these two tables. The foreign key constraint is `contactInfo.empID REFERENCES EMP.empID`, which is many-to-one. That should not be a problem, I guess, since I can directly query the join using SQL.

Please also suggest if I should create the foreign key in the opposite direction.

**More info on failure to create visual**

The exact error message is:

```
Can't display the data because Power BI can't determine 
the relationship between two or more fields.
Version: 2.43.4647.541 (PBIDesktop)
```

***To reproduce the error:***

DB schema is as follows:

[image: schema]

What I want is a table in PowerBI showing contact and sales info of am employee, that is, joining all the four tables. The error will occur when VALUES of the table visual contains "empName, contactDetail, contactType, productName", however, error will NOT occur if I only include "empName, contactDetail, contactType" or "empName, productName". At first I thought the problem may lie in the relationship between contactInfo and emp, but it now seems to be more complicated. I guess it may be caused by multiple one-to-many relationships?

Comment: This seems like a bug in PowerBI to me. I could reproduce it with localdb quite easily. However, what I don't understand: how does this prevent visualizations? Could you extend the question perhaps with some test data and instructions on how to try and create a visualization that won't work? (FWIW: [Here's a minimal repro](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72ef3/1) I used to confirm your bug.)

Comment: @Jeroen Please see additional info in my question.

Comment: The details you've added help, but a [mcve] would be even better. You could add (a) some DDL and DML to set up a minimal test database akin to to the linked example from my previous comment, and (b) add some steps to take in PowerBI to set up the visualization with a problem. This would make it a lot easier for us to help.

Comment: I can see why Power BI is struggling. A single employee can have multiple contacts and multiple sales. But, there's no way for Power BI to know which contactDetail corresponds to which productName, or vice versa (which it needs to know to display them together in a table). I would recommend checking out the star schema data model and the concept of lookup tables: https://powerpivotpro.com/2016/02/data-modeling-power-pivot-power-bi/

Comment: @Leonard I can see what you mean and I think it's the problem. But I don't understand why Power BI cannot repeat every contactDetail for every productName, just as what join operation will do?

Comment: Power BI is designed to roll up numbers. Say you have Total Sales that you want to show by ContactDetail, empName and productName. Power BI needs to know exactly how to divide up your sales to each combination of those columns (which would be impossible to determine with the way the tables are joined). SQL, on the other hand, doesn't have that same objective regarding rolling up numbers, so it's happy to give you every possible combination. (It'd still be difficult to split a sales number by those columns in SQL, but SQL has no compunction about duplicating the same sale in 2+ rows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding my comments to make an answer:

**Root of the Problem**

In your data model, a single employee can have multiple contacts and multiple sales. But, there's no way for Power BI to know which *contactDetail* corresponds to which *productName*, or vice versa (which it needs to know to display them together in a table).

**Deeper Explanation**

Let's say you have 1 *emp* row, that joins to 10 rows in the *sales* table, and 13 rows in the *contactInfo* table. In SQL, if you start from the *emp* row and outer join to the other 2 tables, you'll get back (1*10)*(1*13) rows (130 rows in total). Each row in the *contactInfo table* is repeated for each row in the *sales* table.

That repetition can be a problem if you do something like sum the sales and don't realize a single sales record is repeated 13 times but might be fine otherwise (e.g. if you just want a list of sales and all associated contacts).

**Power BI vs. SQL**

Power BI works slightly differently. Power BI is designed primarily to aggregate numbers, and then break them down by different attributes. E.g. sales by product. Sales by contact. Sales by day. In order to do this, Power BI needs to know 100% how to divide numbers up between the attributes on your table.

*At this point, I'll note that your database diagram doesn't include any obvious metrics that you'd use Power BI to aggregate. However, Power BI doesn't know that. It behaves the same whether you have metrics to aggregate or not. (And failing all else, Power BI can always count your rows to make a metric.)*

Let's say that you have a metric on your *sales* table called *Amt Sold*. If you bring in the *empName*, *productName*, and *Amt Sold* columns, Power BI will know exactly how to divide up *Amt Sold* between *empName* and *ProductName*. There's no problem.

Now add in *contactDetail*. Using your database diagram, Power BI has no way of knowing how an *Amt Sold* metric in the *sales* table relates to a given *contactDetail*. It might know that $100 belongs to *empID* 27. And that *empID* 27 corresponds to 3 records in the *contactInfo* table. But it has no way of knowing how to divide up the $100 between those 3 contacts.

In SQL, what you'd get is 3 contacts, each showing the $100 amount sold. But in Power BI, that would imply $300 was sold, which isn't the case. Even equally dividing the $100 up would be misleading. What if the $100 belonged entirely to 1 contact? So instead, Power BI shows the error you're seeing.

**My Recommendations**

1. If you can, I recommend changing your data model before your bring it in. Power BI works best with a single fact table, which would contain your metrics (like amount sold). You then join this fact table to as many lookup tables as you like (e.g. customer, product, etc.), **directly**. This allows you to slice & dice your metrics with any combination of attributes from any of the lookup tables. I would recommend checking out the star schema data model and the concept of lookup tables: powerpivotpro.com/2016/02/data-modeling-power-pivot-power-bi
2. At the very least, you would want to flatten your tables (i.e. merge the *contactInfo* and *sales* tables into a single table before importing them into your data model.
3. It may be that Power BI isn't the best tool for what you're trying to accomplish. If all you want is a table showing all sales & contact info for an employee, without any associated metrics, a regular reporting tool + SQL query might be a better way to go.

*Side Note: You can't reverse a many:one relationship to get past this error. The* emp *table contains one row per* empID. *Both the* contactInfo *and* sales *tables contain multiple rows with the same* empID. *This means the* emp *table is necessarily the "one" side of the relationship to both those tables. You can't arbitrarily change that.*